# PouchDB sync in Cordova application

Tags: cordova

I am using pouchdb to make my application offline. I have created a couchdb services that create a pouchdb database in local. My code is doing all the things well with the browser. It creates all the docs at local and sync well with remote server. But when I run the code on Cordova application in android platform, then it create the local database but not syncing data with remote couchdb data base… and my services code is as follow:

```
angular.module('couchDB.services', ["pouchdb"]).factory('CouchDBServices', CouchDBServices);

    CouchDBServices.$inject = ['$q'];

/**
 * @name CouchDBServices
 * @desc Singleton service class with static methods for actions with CouchDB.
 * @param $q - service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their return values
 *              when they are done processing
 * @param pouchDB - service with asynchronous APIs for work with couchDB
 * @param SERVER_ADDRESS - constant - remote url to couchdb instance
 */
function CouchDBServices($q) {


    var db = new PouchDB("user");
    console.log( db);
    var remote="https://couchdb-6ea670.smileupps.com/chat";

    PouchDB.sync(db, remote, {live: true, retry: true})

    return {
        getDocument:getDocument,
        getDocuments:getDocuments,
        createDocument:createDocument,
        updateDocument:updateDocument,
        checkUser:checkUser,
        auth:auth,
        conversationExists:conversationExists
    };

    //Document function

    /**
     * @name getDocument
     * @desc  function fetch specific document from couchdb database
     * @param id - document id
     * @returns document
     */
    function getDocument(id){




        console.log("CouchDBServices.getDocument()");
        var q = $q.defer();
        db.get(id).then(function (doc) {
            console.log("success: "+doc);
            q.resolve(doc);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log("error; "+err);
            q.reject(err);
        });
        return q.promise;
    }

    /**
     * @name getDocuments
     * @desc  function fetch document's from couchdb database
     * @param ids - array of documents id
     * @returns documents
     */
    function getDocuments(ids){
        console.log("CouchDBServices.getDocuments()");
        var q = $q.defer();
        db.allDocs({
            keys:ids,
            include_docs:true
        }).then(function (doc) {
            console.log("success: "+doc);
            q.resolve(doc);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log("error; "+err);
            q.reject(err);
        });
        return q.promise;
    }

    /**
     * @name createDocument
     * @desc  function create document in couchdb database
     * @param data - object with key - value properties
     * @returns information about successfully or not successfully created document
     */
    function createDocument(data){
        console.log("CouchDBServices.createDocument()");
        var q = $q.defer();


        db.put(data)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("success: "+JSON.stringify(response));
              q.resolve(response);
            }).catch(function (err) {
                q.reject(err);
              console.log("err: "+err);
            });
        return q.promise;
    }

    /**
     * @name updateDocument
     * @desc  function update specific document in couchdb database
     * @param id - document id
     * @param data - object with key - value properties
     * @returns information about successfully or not successfully created document
     */
    function updateDocument(id,data){
        console.log("CouchDBServices.updateDocument()");
        var q = $q.defer();
        db.get(id).then(function(doc) {
            return db.put(
                data,
                doc._id,
                doc._rev
            );
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log("success: "+response);
            q.resolve(response);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log("err"+err);
            q.reject(err);
        });
        return q.promise;
    }

    //Query methods - uses design documents

    /**
     * @name checkUser
     * @desc  function checks if user (user document) exists in database
     * @param userId - user id ie. document id
     * @returns object with document id and info that user exists,
     *          empty object if not exists and error if something isn't ok
     */
    function checkUser(userId){
        console.log("CouchDBServices.checkUser()");
        var q = $q.defer();
        db.query('user/userExists', {
            key          : userId,
            include_docs : false,
            limit        : 1
        }).then(function (res) {
            console.log("success: "+res);
            q.resolve(res);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            q.reject(err);
            console.log("err: "+err);
        });
        return q.promise;
    }

    /**
     * @name auth
     * @desc  function checks if user (user document) exists in database
     * @param user - object with user phone and password
     * @returns object with user document if exists,
     *          empty object if not exists and error if something isn't ok
     */
    function auth(user){
        console.log("CouchDBServices.auth()");
        var q = $q.defer();
        db.query('user/auth', {
            key         : [user.phone,user.password],
            include_docs : true
        }).then(function (res) {
            console.log("success: "+res);
            q.resolve(res);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            q.reject(err);
            console.log("err: "+err);
        });
        return q.promise;
    }

    /**
     * @name conversationExists
     * @desc  function checks if specific conversation document exists in database
     * @param chatId - id of conversation document
     * @returns object with conversation document if exists,
     *          empty object if not exists and error if something isn't ok
     */
    function conversationExists(chatId){
        console.log("CouchDBServices.conversationExists()");
        var q = $q.defer();
        db.query('conversation/chatExists', {
            key          : chatId,
            include_docs : true,
            limit        : 1
        }).then(function (res) {
            console.log("success: "+res);
            q.resolve(res);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            q.reject(err);
            console.log("err: "+err);
        });
        return q.promise;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are either missing:

1. a connection from the device to your CouchDB,
2. your CouchDB is not bound to 0.0.0.0, it's bound to 127.0.0.1, meaning it can't accept connections from other devices on the network,
3. your CouchDB doesn't have CORS configured (try add-cors-to-couchdb)

It could be any one of these things. Easiest way to figure it out is to inspect the Android device using `chrome://inspect` (open that in Chrome; there are instructions [here](https://developer.chrome.com/home)). Then look in the Network tab and see what the error is.